# DX12 - D3D12GetDebugInterface - app requested interface depends on SDK component missing or mismatched

Tags: debugging, directx-12

I've been trying to figure out how to run some code I got off the internet to understand how to make a proper directX 12 application and when I run it I get the error message below, pointing to the code displayed in the second image down.

I've ran Windows Update several times over and installed the DirectX End-User Runtime Installer and I still get this message. What do I need to do to solve this problem? I'm stumped.
[image: error message]
[image: code]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The DirectX "Debug Layers" for Windows 10 are installed as an 'optional feature' in your Windows installation. Go to the Settings panel, under System, Apps & features, Manage optional Features, Add a feature, and then look for "Graphics Tools".

> The "DirectX End-User Runtime Installer" has not actually changed the version of DirectX installed on any version of Windows since ~2002. It has also never installed the debug runtime. The legacy DirectX SDK only includes an old Windows 7 RTM version of the Debug Layer for DirectX 11.0. On Windows 7 with the KB2670838 installed or Windows 8.x, you need to install the latest Windows SDK to get the debug layers installed.
>
> For more information, see [Direct3D SDK Debug Layer Tricks](https://walbourn.github.io/direct3d-sdk-debug-layer-tricks/) and [Not So Direct Setup](https://walbourn.github.io/not-so-direct-setup/).

Comment: Thank you! This fixed my problem. Now I have to fix other problems that came up because of the changes I made to the file, but this specific issue disappeared.